# How to avoid extra escape characters while variables writing to response file

Tags: install4j

How to avoid extra escape characters while writing string variables to response file

```
install_path=e\:\\myApp
url=https\://10.15.1.66\:443
```

Answer (score 0):

The escaping is a characteristics of the property file format and cannot be changed. You can read the file with `java.lang.Properties`.

You can use a "Write properties to file" action to write a file in UTF-8 encoding, but you have to list all properties separately in that case.

Comment: Which option['direct entry' | 'installer variable'] is best in "Write properties to file" action when it contains around 30 properties ? and also please provide usage sample.

Comment: Whatever works best for you, I cannot not say. A usage sample is `variableName=${installer:variableName}`

Comment: My issue resolved with "Write properties to file" action.